# TypeScript 2.1+ tsconfig extends

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Currently, I am trying the new extends feature in the tsconfig.json that allows developers to have a base tsconfig.json, that other modules can extend / modify.

It is working, although not as expected. Somehow, the only way to get this working is to specifiy compileroptions.lib in both parent and child configs.

**parent.tsconfig.json**

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [ // Lib compiler options defined!!! 
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "resolveGlobs": true,
    "forkChecker": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

**child.tsconfig.json (Expected)**

```
{
  "extends": "../parent.tsconfig.json",
}
```

**child.tsconfig.json (Required to work)**

```
{
  "extends": "../parent.tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ //Have to specify lib again ==> Double-u-t-f
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ]
  }
}
```

Some advice on this matter would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: sourcemap, etc., also don't seem to work for me, no apparent error when using tsc, but VS 2015 complained mightily about missing module and target, too.

Comment: that's strange, it works for us

Comment: I've had a look at the code (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts#L1982) as we've had the same problem. It looks like it should work because it copies anything that isn't in the tsconfig compilerOptions (determined by hasOwnProperty) from the inherited options.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right. Your `tsconfig.json` file should be in the root directory of current project. Double check whether the path of `parent.tsconfig.json` file is correctly set in your `child.tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I run `tsc` command in the parent folder which just use the `tsconfig.json` from parent folder but not the one in child folders.

It works when running `tsc` command in the child folders, or running `tsc -p child_folder_name` from the parent folder also works.